# Upon clicking on my website link a file downloads

Tags: wordpress, cache, download

I'm using hostinger VPS for WordPress hosting (CentOS 7 64bit with CyberPanel
). Wolf plan.
CPU core: 8
RAM: 16GB
Bandwidth: 12TB

But the catch is it's only accessible from my 1 profile on my PC (Brave Browser). But not working from my smartphone.

Theme: Newsmag
Cache: WP Rocket
WordPress: 6.0

I've tried to test it with gtmetix but it says: [image: gtmetrix result]

Here is my webserver: [image]
Here is my cloudflare DNS: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what would be causing it, but your site appears to be served gzipped.  I can run `curl -s https://ashiqtasdid.xyz | gunzip` to see the content.

Comment: I use Cloudflare for CDN and DNS management. Maybe that's why it showing cloudflare

Comment: What web server software did you install on your VPS?  What configuration does it have?

Comment: I closed this question because you indicate that the problem is fixed, but the answer isn't going to be helpful to anybody else in the future with similar problems.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems it was a problem with my caching plugin. I'm using WPRocket. By doing some changes, I fixed it. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Which changes fixed it?